# KCFinder - Is there a way to allow the user to specify the upload folder? Or change the default?

Tags: ckeditor, images, kcfinder

We use images stored in Civi for our CiviMails and our events, and our site is getting nearly a thousand images in the default image folder, sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images. 
(Drupal 7.58, Civi 4.7.27)

As a result, KCFinder is increasingly stalling and not loading the directory tree or any images. This particularly happens for users with poor internet. So, following on from [this earlier question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22549/ckfinder-has-become-terribly-slow-in-civimail), I'm now wondering if there's anyway to either:

1. Allow the user to specify which folder to put uploads into (ideal solution), 
   Or
2. Change the default upload folder.

Where could I go to make these changes?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the "images" folder in the kcfinder browser. You can choose New Subfolder.

[image: kcfinder browser]

Comment: In case it's useful, here is some more info on this: Once you've chosen a subfolder, the upload button in KCFinder then uploads into that subfolder. You do actually have to go into KCFinder and choose this subfolder; if you simply try to upload from the initial IMCE window you will only upload into the images folder.

Comment: And further, once you've chosen a subfolder KCFinder will remember that for you. I think this memory is rather persistent, but if you logout you will need to set it again. Also, of course, each user will have to set this for themselves.